# rotate the list position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 5 item in the list.I want to keep first and last item in same position and need to swap the item list as slider.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
  $(secondLi).before(fourthLi);
  });

 });
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(1)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
   $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69"> 1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299"> 3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<li class="parent">
<div class="node_id"><span>2</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69">1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299">3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```

If I click the next button 1,2,3 scrolls fine as expected.I have tried to reverse the swap using 'after' for 'prev' button.It works wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the behavior that you are looking for?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
  $(secondLi).before(fourthLi);
  });

 });
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
   $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69"> 1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299"> 3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<li class="parent">
<div class="node_id"><span>2</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li class="69">1</li>
  <li class="233">2</li>
  <li class="299">3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>
<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your click event for the prev button, you should change the index value to 4,

```
var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
```

Currently, you are passing 1 to it hence, the swapping is occurring between the first 2 elements only.